# Parse "or" query with limit returns all records ignoring limit on single query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

When using a Parse "or" Query operator, is there a bug when attempting to use limits within a single query? 
Nothing is documented on their site regarding the or operator in conjunction with the limit operator, but an example query I have come up with is wanting to fetch the last occurrence of a record, and all future records of a given type.

I write the query like this:

```
var Appointment = Parse.Object.extend("Appointment");
var Client = Parse.Object.extend("Client");
var query = new Parse.Query(Client);
query.equalTo("objectId",client.id);

//get the last appointment whose start date occurs prior to now
var pastAppointmentQuery = new Parse.Query(Appointment);
pastAppointmentQuery.matchesQuery("Clients", query);
pastAppointmentQuery.lessThanOrEqualTo("Start",new Date());
pastAppointmentQuery.descending("Start").limit(1);

//get future appointments whose start date occurs after now (no limit)
var futureAppointmentQuery = new Parse.Query(Appointment);
futureAppointmentQuery.matchesQuery("Clients", query);
futureAppointmentQuery.greaterThanOrEqualTo("Start",new Date());
var compoundQuery = Parse.Query.or(pastAppointmentQuery,futureAppointmentQuery)
.find().then(function(appts){//....});
```

With today's date, this returns all prior records, as well as all future records, completely ignoring the limit imposed by the first query within the "or" operator. Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not stated in the API docs, but does make an appearance in the [developer's guide](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-compound-queries):

> Note that we do not, however, support GeoPoint or non-filtering constraints (e.g. near, withinGeoBox, limit, skip, ascending/descending, include) in the subqueries of the compound query.

Comment: Thanks for that- hopefully the API docs get open sourced so we can modify them when parse goes fully open source.

Comment: Anything new to that? Is there a way now to apply a limit to "or" queries?